# How to pass an extra column to table in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, flat-file

I have a flatfile...and have a SQLSErver table. 
I need to copy the data from flatfile to table. The flat file has 10 columns...I am able to copy all 10 columns.

But I have **one more column in table**..."Extract Date". In this column I have to insert GetDate() value.

How can I do this ?

**NOTE :** I have 3 dataflow tasks :- 1)FlatFile Connection, 2)Derived column edtor (to trim values..and pass null if it's empty). 3)OLEDB Destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either give the ExtractDate column a default of getdate() on the table itself, or, in SSIS, add a new column to the Derived Column Task with GETDATE() as the expression, and pass this to the OleDb destination.

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss